# Including a file when publishing to Azure Cloud Functions from Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I am trying to publish an executable file from my project C#.NET project folder into the Azure Cloud Functions. It would seem like any file, whether exe or other file type (like .json) will not be published into Azure even if the file is inside the project folder. That is, running:

```
func azure functionapp publish myproject
```

Does nothing except publishing the base project files into Azure Cloud Function.

I am using Visual Studio Code with Azure Functions Core Tools:

> Core Tools Version:       4.0.5095
>
> Function Runtime Version: 4.16.5.20396.

Is there a way to include other files than what the project delivers?

Answer (score 0):

You can publish extra files by defining following lines inside your .csproj file:

```
<!-- Copy the EXE file to output -->
<Target Name="CopyExe" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Message Text="Executing CopyExe task" Importance="High" />
    
    <!-- This will copy the file to your local environment, making "func start" to work-->
    <Copy
      SourceFiles=".\yourfilepathinsidetheproject\yourfile.exe"
      DestinationFolder=".\bin\output" /> <!-- change to whatever you want the final path to be -->

    <!-- This will copy the file to your Azure Cloud Function, making "func azure functionapp publish yourproject" to work-->
    <Copy
      SourceFiles=".\yourfilepathinsidetheproject\yourfile.exe"
      DestinationFolder=".\bin\publish" /> <!-- change to whatever you want the final path to be -->

    <Message Text="Copied build files" Importance="High" />
</Target>
```

Note that there are two different copy commands inside the code. The first one will copy the file when you make a build and run your local environment with command:

```
func start
```

The second copy will copy the file into Azure Cloud Functions after you run deploy with:

```
func azure functionapp publish yourproject
```